# Как реализовать ограниченный лог?

Tags: java

Нужно сделать лог определенного размера в который можно бесконечно добавлять записи в виде строк но при этом когда некуда будет записывать новые записи старые будут затираться, мне тяжело сформулировать мысль, покажу на примере кода:

```
MyLog log = new Mylog(1024); // создание лога размером в 1024 записи
log.add("запись в логе #1"); // добавляем запись
log.add("запись в логе #2"); // ещё добавляем запись
...
log.add("запись в логе #1025); // запись #1 затирается все строки сдвигаются и запись #1025 становится в конец
String[] arr = log.toArray(); // Возвращает массив из 1024 строк
```

Как такое оптимальнее всего сделать?

Возможно есть какое-то название для этого "лога", разновидность стека какая нибудь там?

Сложность вставки в худшей случае будет O(n) или еще больше?

И да, возможно есть это в стандартной библиотеке?

Comment: Это называется [circular log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Чаще используют название Circular Buffer, но он имеет свойство бросать ошибку при переполнении,  не затирать наиболее устаревшие записи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю можно сделать таким образом:

1. `MyLog log = new Mylog(1024);` - создается массив из 1024 элемента
2. Курсор при создании = 0

   ```
   this.cursor = 0;
   this.perepolneniye = FASLE;
   ```
3. функция Add() добавляет запись и передвигает курсор

   ```
   public void add(String logData){
       this.cursor ++;
       if (this.cursor > MAX_SIZE) {
           this.cursor = 0;
           this.perepolneniye = TRUE;
       }
       logArray[this.cursor] = logData;
   }
   ```
4. Теперь когда нужно все это собрать и распечатать, нужно с начало собрать из `cursor + 1` до конца и потом из начало до `cursor`'а. Но если не было переполнения, тогда только с начало до `cursor`'а.

   ```
   public void outResult(){
       String result = "";
       if (this.perepolneniye) {
           // Собираем от this.cursor+1 до MAX_SIZE
       }
       // Собираем от 0 до this.cursor
       return result;
   }
   ```

Comment: Насколько я понял ТС, ему надо при переполнении не с начала массива данные вставлять, а так же в конец, но чтобы первый элемент стирался... Тут ваш `add()` не подойдёт.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы правильно поняли. Я тоже предлагаю добавлять с конца. Только я предлагаю вместо передвигать элементы массива передвигать курсор начала массива. То есть, у меня, если есть переполнение курсор будет ровнатся на конец массива а cursor+1 это начало массива

Comment: А-а-а! Точно, понял) Интересное решение)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдет тип данных [очередь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29) (разновидность списка), с той оговоркой, что при добавлении элемента будет проверяться длина очереди и, если надо, последний элемент будет выталкиваться. Сложность вставки будет О(1), но вот получение и изменение n-го элемента будет O(n). В джава нет встроенного типа данных очередь, но есть `LinkedList`, на основе которого можно легко сделать соответствующий класс:

```
class Log<T> {
    public int max_log_length;  //максимальная длина
    public LinkedList<T> list; //собственно список элементов

    public Log(int len) {
        this.list = new LinkedList<T>();
        this.max_log_length = len;
    }

    public void addFirst(T t) {
        this.list.addFirst(t);
        if (this.list.size() > this.max_log_length) {
            this.list.removeLast();
        }
    }

    public T get(int index) {
       return this.list.get(index);
    }

    public void set(int index, T t) {
        this.list.set(index, t);
    }
}
```

Использовать соответственно так:

```
Log<String> log = new Log<String>(1024);
```

Получить из него массив можно так:

```
String[] log_array = log.list.toArray(new String[b.max_log_length]);
```

Естественно надо еще добавить различные проверки на выход за границы списка и много чего другого.